# C# constructors overloading

Tags: c#, constructor, constructor-overloading

How I can use constructors in C# like this:

```
public Point2D(double x, double y)
{
    // ... Contracts ...

    X = x;
    Y = y;
}

public Point2D(Point2D point)
{
    if (point == null)
        ArgumentNullException("point");
    Contract.EndContractsBlock();

    this(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

I need it to not copy code from another constructor...

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can factor out your common logic to a private method, for example called `Initialize` that gets called from both constructors.

Due to the fact that you want to perform argument validation you cannot resort to constructor chaining.

Example:

```
public Point2D(double x, double y)
{
    // Contracts

    Initialize(x, y);
}

public Point2D(Point2D point)
{
    if (point == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("point");

    // Contracts

    Initialize(point.X, point.Y);
}

private void Initialize(double x, double y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}
```

Comment: As an avid fan of immutability, I'd like to note that a drawback of this method is that you cannot initialize readonly fields :(

Comment: I was thinking of this exact same solution, and now you confirmed it's a good idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Try Mark Cidade's answer first. Use this one as a fallback.

Answer (score 221):

```
public Point2D(Point2D point) : this(point.X, point.Y) { }
```

Comment: point cannot be null because it is not defined as a nullable type (Point2D? point)

Comment: Describe what you mean by using Contracts.  Mark's answer is right.

Comment: @PowerRoy, you are assuming `Point2D` is a value type. If it's a class it may be null.

Comment: @PowerRoy: point can be null because... we don't know how it is defined.

Comment: No, Point2D may be null. But second constructor copy the point, so parameter point can not be null.

Comment: You should make your Point2D a struct.

Comment: Thanks.. For other people: If you pass just ": this" with no arguments - for example, the both - empty constructor code plus the overloading constructor code will run. Useful in case that the overloading constructor has the same code as the empty + new code.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your class isn't quite complete. Personally, I use a private init() function with all of my overloaded constructors.

```
class Point2D {

  double X, Y;

  public Point2D(double x, double y) {
    init(x, y);
  }

  public Point2D(Point2D point) {
    if (point == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("point");
    init(point.X, point.Y);
  }

  void init(double x, double y) {
    // ... Contracts ...
    X = x;
    Y = y;
  }
}
```