# Constructor that takes 1 argument

Tags: c#

I have a constructor that takes 2 arguments although I don't know how to write it.

```
// Home.CS:
var menu = new menu (dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring());
```

I don't know how to write the second argument in the code above

```
// Menu.cs
public Menu (string role, string Millitary)
initializeComponet();
Label1.Text = Role;
Label2.Text = Millitary;
```

Comment: Any help would be nice

Comment: What do you expect as end result? Should `Military` be null?

Comment: There are too many syntax errors. Consider to copy/paste real code.

Comment: `var menu = new Menu(dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring(), string.Empty);`

Also rename `Millitary` to `Military`.

Comment: Look at constructor overloading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555715/c-sharp-constructors-overloading. Passing in an empty string or null is a pretty rough API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If second argument is not required then you can pass any value as

```
var menu = new Menu (dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring(),string.Empty);
```

Or if the value of both is to be same then pass same parameter twice as you mentioned in comment

```
var menu = new Menu (dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring(),dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring());
```

Comment: It is required, it is the same as the first argument

Comment: Why not duplicate the first argument then?

Comment: var menu = new Menu (dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring(),dt.Rows[0][0].Tostring());

Are you expecting this?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

In side the () so if only one was required it would be (FirstArgument) if 2 are required its (FirstArgument , SecondArgument) etc. using a "," as the seperator

Comment: That you so much for the help